# Implementing IoT PowerBI table schema

Tags: json, azure, iot

I'm currently implementing an IoT solution that has a bunch of sensors sending information in JSON format through a gateway.

I was reading about doing this on azure but couldn't quite figure out how the JSON scheme and the Event Hubs work to display the info on PowerBI?

Can I create a schema and upload it to PowerBI then connect it to my device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's multiple sides to this. To start with, the IoT ingestion in Azure is done tru Event Hubs as you've mentioned. If your gateway is able to do a RESTful call to the Event Hubs entry point, Event Hubs will get this data and store it temporarily for the retention period specified. Then stream analytics, will consume the data from Event Hubs and will enable you to do further processing and divert the data to different outputs. In your case, you can set one of the outputs to be a PowerBI dashboard which you can authorize with an organizational account (more on that later) and the output will automatically tied to PowerBI. The data schema part is interesting, the JSON itself defines the data table schema to be used on PowerBI side and will propagate from EventHubs to Stream Analytics to PowerBI with the first JSON package sent. Once the schema is there it is fixed and the rest of the data being streamed in should be in the same format.

If you don't have an organizational account at hand to use with PowerBI, you can register your domain under Azure Active Directory and use that account since it is considered within your org.

There may be a way of altering the schema afterwards using PowerBI rest api. Kindly find the links below..Haven't tried it myself tho.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt203557.aspx

[Stream analytics with powerbi](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-power-bi-dashboard/)

Hope this helps, let me know if you need further info.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is to send your data to Azure Events Hub, read it and send it to PowerBI with Stream Analytics.  Listing all the steps here would be too long.  I suggest that you take a look at a series of blog posts I wrote describing how I built a demo similar to what you try to achieve.  That should give you enough info to get you started.

http://guyb.ca/IoTAzureDemo

Comment: Will definitely look more into it for further work, thanks a lot!