# Sending data to Azure Events Hub from an external API REST

Tags: c#, rest, api, azure

Like this topic : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32843290/implementing-iot-powerbi-table-schema/32844087#32844087](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32843290/implementing-iot-powerbi-table-schema/32844087#32844087://), I would like to retrieve data from an API REST to create a dashboard which will refresh in real time the data taken from the API.

In order to do that, I have to go through Azure Events Hubs to get the data taken from the API. I have troubles dealing with how to retrieve the data from the API to put it in the entry point of Azure Events Hub. I know I have to write a program (preferably by using Visual Studio) and make this program retrieve the data from the API and put it in the Event Hub but I have difficulties to see how I should begin. What kind of program and what I would need.

I tried to find some tutorial/codes about this but couldn't find anything about retrieving from external API.

From what I can understand, I need to write a program that connects to the Events Hub (not difficult), retrieve the data of the API, store it in a variable created and send it to Events Hub. I would like a bit help on how to start, where to start, what classes for example I would need etc...

I am not an expert on API at all, but I have some knowledge. For information this is the website from which I am trying to retrieve data from : https://data.sncf.com/api/en. The use of the API allows us to retrieve information in a json format if I am correct and I will have to save this data to store it in a variable ?

Thank you.

Comment: @ Robby,Would you like to show your data using PBI or website which you created?

Comment: @WillShao-MSFT I want to show my data using PBI. But I am a bit confused. Now I have created a class libraries with a scrapper, a workerrole and I am a bit lost on how to make a main, an executable to run the program...

Answer (score 1):

Per my understanding, I assumed that you could try to follow the steps below to achieve your purpose.

1.Use [Azure WebJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs) to call your API periodically, then send the data retrieved from the API to Azure EventHub;

You could follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs) for getting started with WebJob by using VS. Also, you could follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620278/how-do-i-make-calls-to-a-rest-api-using-c) for making calls to a REST API via C#. For a simple way, you could leverage [EventHub bindings](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/EventHub-support) supported by azure-webjobs-sdk to send messages to an event hub after you retrieved data from REST API.

2.For your client-side, you could follow the official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-csharp-ephcs-getstarted) to receive messages from EventHub via `EventProcessorHost`.